# Como unir o contador de cliques com uma função que modifica a imagem em ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, react

Olá, pessoal. Estou tentado adicionar um easter egg a minha pokedex. Quando o usuário clicar três vezes na imagem do pikachu o background da aplicação deverá mudar. Já consegui adicionar o contador de cliques no botão mas não consigo mudar a imagem. Alguém sabe como posso resolver?

```
import ProgressBar from "@ramonak/react-progress-bar";

const InfoPokemon = ({ data }) => {
    const [contador, setContador] = useState(0);


    return (
        <>
            {
                (!data) ? "" : (
                    <>
                        {data.name !== 'pikachu' ? (
                            <h1>{data.name}</h1>
                        ) : (

                            <button className="btn-hover"
                                onClick={() => setContador(contador + 1)}

                            >

--aqui exibi a quantidade de cliques só pra verificar se está contando certinho--
                                Você clicou {contador} vezes</button>




                        )}
                        <img src={`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/other/dream-world/${data.id}.svg`} alt="" id='pikachu' />
                        <div className="habilidades">
                            {
                                data.abilities.map(poke => {
                                    return (
                                        <>
                                            <div className="grupo">
                                                <h2>{poke.ability.name}</h2>
                                            </div>
                                        </>
                                    )
                                })
                            }

                        </div>
                        <div className="status">

                            {
                                data.stats.map(poke => {
                                    return (
                                        <>
                                            <ProgressBar className="containerP" completed={poke.base_stat} customLabel={poke.stat.name} />
                                        </>
                                    )
                                })
                            }
                        </div>
                    </>
                )
            }

        </>
    )
}
export default InfoPokemon;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Cara, nessa situação da pra criar uma constante que retorna a imagem dependendo do contador, então eu criei uma constante:

```js
const pokemonImage = contador >= 3 ? `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/other/dream-world/${data.id}.svg` : 'outra imagem'
```

Ai nessa "outra imagem" você bota o link correto da imagem que você quer.
Mudei também o setContador do onClick pra não dar problema na hora de armazenar o valor:

```js
setContador((c) => c + 1)
```

O código geral ficou assim:

```js
import ProgressBar from "@ramonak/react-progress-bar";

const InfoPokemon = ({ data }) => {
  const [contador, setContador] = useState(0);

  const pokemonImage = contador >= 3 ? `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/other/dream-world/${data.id}.svg` : 'outra imagem'

  return (
    <>
      {
        (!data) ? "" : (
          <>
            {data.name !== 'pikachu' ? (
              <h1>{data.name}</h1>
            ) : (

              <button className="btn-hover"
                onClick={() => setContador((c) => c + 1)}>

                --aqui exibi a quantidade de cliques só pra verificar se está contando certinho--
                Você clicou {contador} vezes</button>
            )}
            <img src={pokemonImage} alt="" id='pikachu' />
            <div className="habilidades">
              {
                data.abilities.map(poke => {
                  return (
                    <>
                      <div className="grupo">
                        <h2>{poke.ability.name}</h2>
                      </div>
                    </>
                  )
                })
              }
            </div>
            <div className="status">
              {
                data.stats.map(poke => {
                  return (
                    <>
                      <ProgressBar className="containerP" completed={poke.base_stat} customLabel={poke.stat.name} />
                    </>
                  )
                })
              }
            </div>
          </>
        )
      }
    </>
  )
}
export default InfoPokemon;
```

Comment: Nossa, cara. Mil vezes obrigada. Ajudou muito, valeu mesmo pela atenção!!

Comment: Nada kkkk, se puder dar aquele check 